# How to fool apple store (parsing)

Tags: python, ios, parsing, html-parsing, python-requests

I'm trying to get app info from apple store, but can't fully imitate a real browser:

```
import requests
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36'}
# got this user-agent from my own browser where this page opens perfectly though I don't have iTunes installed
store=requests.get('https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/real-racing-3/id556164350', headers=headers)
print store.text
```

and I'm getting `We are unable to find iTunes on your computer.` error, not the info I need.
Hope there is a better way to do it without using [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) e.g.

Comment: Just a guess: Maybe cookies are a problem? Also what browser did you use to get this user agent? Mine is "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0" (Firefox, Windows) - maybe something is wrong here?

Comment: Nice title by the way :)

Comment: How does the page look when you open it in the browser? On mac, it tries to launch iTunes. On windows, it redirects me to the "Download iTunes" page..

Comment: @katze_sonne it's Google Chrome, tried with yours, same result, now playing with cookies, nothing yet

Comment: @alecxe like this http://s27.postimg.org/a697p5hwj/screenshot_625.png (it's in Russian, for some reason English version redirects me to 'download itunes' page) (no, I cant use RU version in parser - it gives the same error, just in Russian)
Also here is the exact page that the parses receives http://s27.postimg.org/akajor203/screenshot_637.png and the code for it - http://pastebin.com/PKsxxRTG

Answer (score 1):

Okay, guys I eventually came up with this:

```
import gtk
import webkit

web = webkit.WebView()
web.open('http://google.com/')


def load_finished(webview, frame):
    data = web.get_main_frame().get_data_source().get_data()
    print data[:20]
    gtk.main_quit()

web.connect("load-finished", load_finished)

gtk.main()
```